# How to specify base directory for FUSE filesystem?

Tags: mount, fuse

I am trying to create a FUSE filesystem called `ordered-dirs` using the Haskell wrapper over libfuse, [HFuse](https://github.com/m15k/hfuse). This filesystem is a "derived filesystem", i.e. it takes an existing directory (the "base directory") and produces a different view of it.

However, when I try to run my FUSE filesystem program, specifying the arguments in the ordinary `mount` way, I get an error:

```
$ ordered-dirs /home/robin/tasks/ /home/robin/to
fuse: invalid argument `/home/robin/to'
```

There is no way in HFuse (or in libfuse, it seems) to get the base directory (the first argument), so I had just written my own code to get it. But it's not this code that's failing - it's code within C libfuse itself - as the error message indicates.

So what is the correct way to pass the base directory to a fuse filesystem executable that uses libfuse to parse its arguments?

Comment: Weird! `mount.fuse` has _always_ passed the arguments to the FUSE filesystem executable in this order, ever since it was created 11 years ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, it seems that the way to do this is to simply strip the base directory argument from the command-line arguments that are parsed to the libfuse parser, so that libfuse never sees it.

In the particular case of HFuse, this can be done by calling `fuseRun` instead, which allows the command-line arguments to be passed in explicitly. You can see how I've done this [here](https://github.com/greenrd/ordered-dirs/blob/06e95a848dde68f3e576830c351e90645852f492/app/Main.hs#L40) - here is the relevant code (in which I've called the base directory `source`):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (maybeSource, remainder) = extractSource args
    source <- maybe (fail "source not specified") return maybeSource
    fuseRun "ordered-dirs" remainder (orderedDirOps source) defaultExceptionHandler
```

Comment: This applicable to C also, just provide &argv[1] and argc - 1